# Anonymous methods passing in arguments

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, java-8, spark-graphx

I have created a method inside Pregel which has the following signature:

```
Graph<VD, ED> org.apache.spark.graphx.Pregel.apply(Graph<VD, ED> arg0,
A arg1, int arg2, EdgeDirection arg3, 
Function3<Object, VD, A, VD> arg4, 
Function1<EdgeTriplet<VD, ED>, Iterator<Tuple2<Object, A>>> arg5, 
Function2<A, A, A> arg6, ClassTag<VD> arg7, 
ClassTag<ED> arg8, ClassTag<A> arg9)
```

As the image shows I am calling that method:

[image: Methods implemented]

But I am facing the following error

```
The method apply(Graph<VD,ED>, A, int, EdgeDirection, 
Function3<Object,VD,A,VD>, Function1<EdgeTriplet<VD,ED>,Iterator<Tuple2<Object,A>>>, 
Function2<A,A,A>, ClassTag<VD>, ClassTag<ED>, ClassTag<A>) in the type Pregel is not applicable for the arguments 
(Graph<Row,Row>, double, int, EdgeDirection, new Function3<Row,Double,Double,Double>(){}, 
new Function1<EdgeTriplet<Double,Double>,Iterator<Tuple2<Long,Double>>>(){}, 
new Function2<Double,Double,Double>(){}, ClassTag<VD>, ClassTag<ED>, ClassTag<A>)
```

What is the mistake I am making here while calling this method?

Answer (score 3):

Well, your generics are all messed up. `VD` and `ED` are both `Row` according to the first parameter. That means `arg4` should be of type `Function3<Object, Row, Double, Row>` instead of `Function3<Row,Double,Double,Double>`. The other parameters are equally off. In many places where you write `Double` it should actually be `Row` (or all `Row`s should be `Double`s). Just write down what values each generic type should have and check wether or not your parameters all match that statements.